# How likely are you to get infected with Hepatitis C from coming into contact with objects contaminated with blood?

Tags: virus, hepatitis

Lets say that someone with a small fresh cut/wound touches an object that has been contaminated with Hep C blood and then touches his wound(the virus comes in to contract with the wound).What are the chances that they will be infected with Hep C? I did a search but I didn't find anything close to my question. The only thing that I found that was close was the chances of needle stick injury, which are somewhere around 3%. Will this scenario have the same chances as that?.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that's extremely difficult to test experimentally (are you going to have a group of people cut themselves, touch something contaminated with hep C, and see how many are infected? how do you standardize or parameterize the level of contact? virus titre?), and not particularly useful: better to just a) avoid all such contact regardless of the exact risk, and b) for people potentially exposed, just test! It doesn't matter what the overall probability is, it matters whether the person in front of you is positive or not.

Comment: Also, there are so many variables here: viral load of the positive person, amount of blood, how long the blood was exposed to air, how exposed and fresh the open wound is, immune status of the negative person, and probably others. I think any estimate is going to be nothing more than an educated guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys.